# Merge sort single function

Tags: c

I'm trying to merge sort recursively, in a single function.

How can I fix this code to get the correct output?

```
void merge(int a[], int left, int right)
{
    if(left < right)
    {
        int mid = (left + right) / 2;
        merge(a, left, mid);  
        merge(a, mid + 1, right); 

        int b[mid - left + 1], c[right - mid]; 
        //two half arrays of the original array 'a'

        int i, j, k;
        for(i = left, j = 0; i <= mid; i++, j++) 
            b[j] = a[i];
        for(j = mid + 1, i = 0; j <= right; j++, i++)  
            c[i] = a[j];
        i = 0;   
        j = 0;   
        k =- 1;  
        while(k < (right - left + 1))   
        {   
            k++;
            if(i == (mid - left + 1))    
                a[k] = c[j++];
            else if(j == (right - mid))   
                a[k] = b[i++];
            else if(b[i] < c[j]) 
                a[k] = b[i++];
            else  
                a[k] = c[j++];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: What's the input, what's the output?

Comment: input is integer array, output is the same array sorted in ascending order.

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke, what litterally the input you provide and what your sort function return. `int b[mid-left+1],c[right-mid];` compile?

Comment: Maybe have a look at this page: http://www.personal.kent.edu/~rmuhamma/Algorithms/MyAlgorithms/Sorting/mergeSort.htm. Could you please format your output with the corret indentations. The code given is a mess.

Comment: @Prajwal I have formatted your code a bit better. When asking questions in the future please format your code batter. You are more likely to get answers if it is easier for people to read your code - otherwise why should they bother? It also makes it easier for *you* to spot any errors.

Comment: You cannot mergesort without a temp; source and target will interfere. Try the string "ADBC": the D will be overwritten before it can be picked as source. (note: You *can* merge sort without a swaptemp, but the bookkeeping is quite complex ...)